# Битрикс задать значение свойства типа "Привязка к элементам" для элемента инфоблока через API

Tags: php, битрикс

Для добавления значения свойства типа "Строка" использую код:

```
$elementModel = new CIBlockElement();
$data_prop['ATT_ART'] = 'Тестовый артикул';
$data = array(
    'NAME' => 'Тест',
    'IBLOCK_ID' => IBLOCK_CATALOG_ID,
    'PROPERTY_VALUES' => $data_prop
);
$elementModel->Add($data);
```

Как добавить значение свойства "Привязка к элементу" при создании элемента инфоблока через api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того что бы при задать значение свойства типа `Привязка к элементам` при вызове метода [CIblockElement::Add](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/add.php) достаточно указать `ID элемента инфоблока` который Вы хотите привязать.

Например у нас есть свойство типа `Привязка к элементам` с символьным кодом `ELEMENT`. Тогда код будет примерно следующий (см. на `$arProps`):

```
//Если ядро старое, то CModule::includeModule('iblock');
Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule('iblock'); 

//Массив пользовательских свойств
$arProps = [
    'ELEMENT' => '8' //ID элемента
];

//Массив для добавления нового элемента
$arNewEl = [
    'IBLOCK_ID' => 2,
    'NAME' => 'Новый элемент',
    'PREVIEW_TEXT' => 'Краткое описание',
    'ACTIVE' => 'Y',
    'PROPERTY_VALUES' => $arProps
];

$obIblockEl = new CIblockElement();

//Добавляем элемент в инфоблок
$newElementId = $obIblockEl->add($arNewEl);
if ($newElementId) {
    echo $newElementId;
} else {
    echo $obIblockEl->LAST_ERROR;
}
```